# Searching for multiple specific words in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, search, text, excel-formula

I've seen several examples of Excel formulas that can search for multiple words in a cell like so:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(NOT(ISERR(SEARCH({"mail","post"},A4)))))>0,1,"")
```

And:

```
=OR(NOT(ISERR(SEARCH("mail",A4))),NOT(ISERR(SEARCH("post",A4))))
```

However, the results will pick up any instance of "mail" (i.e. "mail" or "email") or "post" (i.e. "post" or "posture"). Is there a way to run a search for multiple words and only the specific words listed?

Comment: can you describe your input and output of what you are trying to do?

Comment: You would have to include word boundaries in your search functions if the cell contains multiple words.  If you are just looking at cells that contain single words, then you would do an equality test, rather than a SEARCH.

Answer (score 1):

Following the scheme:

[image]

The formula consider to search some char of end for words like "." (in a array).
Search this char **before** and **after** to try to define the complete word.
If you need to search only the first occurrance you can use EXCEL:

```
B3 -> =IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(MID(A2;SEARCH(B2;A2)+LEN(B2);1);{" ";"-";".";",";";";":"};1;);FALSE)=FALSE;FALSE;TRUE)
B4 -> =OR(SEARCH(B2;A2)=1;IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(MID(A2;SEARCH(B2;A2)-1;1);{" ";"-";".";",";";";":"};1;);FALSE)=FALSE;FALSE;TRUE))
B5 -> =AND(B3;B4)
```

If you need to search for EACH occurrance it's better to use VBA:

```
Public Function FindWords(xx As Range, Stri As String) As Boolean
    For i = 1 To Len(xx.Value)
        If Mid(xx.Value, i, Len(Stri)) = Stri Then
            If (i = 1) Then
                If InStr(1, " ,.-;:_", Mid(xx.Value, i + Len(Stri), 1)) > 0 Or (i + 1 + Len(Stri) > Len(xx.Value)) Then
                    FindWords = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            ElseIf (InStr(1, " ,.-;:_", Mid(xx.Value, i - 1, 1)) > 0) Then
                If InStr(1, " ,.-;:_", Mid(xx.Value, i + Len(Stri), 1)) > 0 Or (i + Len(Stri) > Len(xx.Value)) Then
                    FindWords = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    FindWords = False
End Function
```

Adding the function in a Module:

```
B7 -> =FindWords(A2;B2)
```